# StackOverflow Exception work around (intermittent - 3-4 hours before thrown)?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Sorry a little new to programming, hope you can help with this.

I realize this exception has been covered quite a lot and I have done a fair bit of googling/stackoverflow searching to try and find a way around it.

The code I have only seems to produce the exception after running for over 3-4 hours? The program is set to loop continuously on a permanent basis. I have a PHP page linking the data that's posted to an SQL page which is working fine.

Can someone take a look at my coding and recommend a way for me to prevent/avoid the stackoverflow exception? The program needs too loop and run every few seconds so the SQL database keep up to date.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also sorry for the code dump, not entirely sure which part is at fault,if not all! :)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace ClientApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Client";
        CheckOnline();
    }
    private static void CallCheckOnline()
    {
        CheckOnline();
    }
    private static void CheckOnline()
    {
        try
        {
            PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
            cpuCounter.NextValue();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            int CPUCounter = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();

            XElement xml = new XElement("Client");
            XElement hostname = new XElement("hostname", Dns.GetHostName());
            XElement status = new XElement("status", "Online");
            XElement counter = new XElement("counter", CPUCounter.ToString() + "%");

            xml.Add(hostname);
            xml.Add(status);
            xml.Add(counter);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/receiver.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            xml.Save(request.GetRequestStream());
            HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("General Exception Occurred");
            Console.WriteLine("Packed Message: " + Ex.Message);
            Console.Write("Call Stack: " + Ex.StackTrace);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        }
        CallCheckOnline();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's a pretty obvious Stack Overflow at play here; your `CheckOnline` calls `CallCheckOnline` at the end of it, and that then calls `CheckOnline`, which repeats the cycle. This may be one implementation of an infinite loop, but every time something is called, it adds to the call stack, which isn't infinite.

Comment: In order to achieve this loop without a stack overflow, I'd get rid of `CallCheckOnline` entirely, and just change your `Main` to read: `while (true) { CheckOnline(); }`. This way, your call stack only gets a method or two deep, then returns out of that method before it is called again on the next while-loop iteration.

Comment: The reason it's intermittent and takes a while to achieve is that the contents of `CheckOnline()` take a long time to complete. If you weren't doing network communication, you'd exhaust the call stack almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `CheckOnline` method you are calling `CallCheckOnline()` which is calling the same method (`CheckOnline`) again. This is a infinite recursion and is bound to run into `StackOverflow` exception.  The only reason you are not running in to this exception right away is the the delays using `Thread.Sleep` and possibly longer execution time of your actual routine.

It appears you are trying to perform an operation periodically. You should search for `Timers`. There are plenty of example of its usage over internet. Also consider making a windows service application, if this process has to execute continuously in the background.

Answer (score 1):

A method calling itself endlessly will lead to this situation. You are better off have the calls to `CheckOnline()` inside of a loop and remove the call `CheckOnline()` makes to itself.

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "Client";
    while(true)
    {
        CheckOnline();
    }
}
```